# When rendering an animation, it only renders part of the animation

Tags: rendering

When I tried rendering my animation, it rendered the first 50 frames or so, but when I came back to check on its progress, it was rendering and the frame count was going up, but nothing was appearing in the render screen. In the output folder for my render, about 50 images were there, and all of the others were black images. [image: The output folder]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add images of your render settings and other information about your scene.

Comment: Check your UI, or the "Dope Sheet", or the "Outliner" in case you accidentally animated any values that would do this, such as the lighting, or the camera. It can happen when you have the "Automatic Keyframe Insertion" button on, since it animates anything you change.